# Calculating Legendre symbol of 6 over p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm really stuck on calculating the Legendre symbol of (6/p); I'm looking over old MSE questions on the topic but none have really helped me out. I tried at first to do (6/p) = (3/p)(2/p) but the issue I ran into here is that I couldn't combine these using the Chinese Remainder Theorem as gcd(8,12) doesn't equal 1; I found out there was a generalised version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem for non-coprime moduleses, but I'm not allowed to use this as it wasn't in my module. So really stuck, not sure what to do here.

Obviously, (2/p) equals 1 if p = +-1 (mod 8) and equals -1 if p = +- 3 (mod 8). I also know that (3/p) equals 1 if p = +- 1 (mod 12), and equals -1 if p = +-5 (mod 12). But I'm less sure on why this is the case in all honesty.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145735/discussion-on-question-by-keynesianspaceman-calculating-legendre-symbol-of-6-ove); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.